HTML Button w/ jQuery $('CLASS').on('click tap touchstart', function(event) not working on mobile (Wordpress BricksBuilder)
I've edited the code from the last time I posted this question using some advice, unfortunately the 'DUPLICATE' that I was linked to also did not fix the problem. Here is the code I'm working with:
<button class="brxe-button main-cta-button pricing-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">Pricing</button>
<button class="brxe-button main-cta-button plans-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">Plans</button>
<button class="brxe-button main-cta-button seo-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">SEO</button>
<button class="brxe-button main-cta-button websites-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">Websites</button>

<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container pricing-faq bricks-lazy-hidden">Pricing</div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container pricing-faq bricks-lazy-hidden">Plans</div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container pricing-faq bricks-lazy-hidden">SEO</div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container pricing-faq bricks-lazy-hidden">Websites</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('.faq-btn').on('click tap touchstart', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if($(this).hasClass('pricing-btn')){

        $('.pricing-faq').show();
        $('.plans-faq').hide();
        $('.seo-faq').hide();
        $('.websites-faq').hide();
      
        $('.pricing-btn').css("background-color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.plans-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.seo-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.websites-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
      
        $('.pricing-btn').css("color", "#fff");
        $('.plans-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.seo-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.websites-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");

    } else if ($(this).hasClass('plans-btn')){

        $('.pricing-faq').hide();
        $('.plans-faq').show();
        $('.seo-faq').hide();
        $('.websites-faq').hide();

        $('.pricing-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.plans-btn').css("background-color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.seo-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.websites-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
      
        $('.pricing-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.plans-btn').css("color", "#fff");
        $('.seo-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.websites-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");

    } else if ($(this).hasClass('seo-btn')){

        $('.pricing-faq').hide();
        $('.plans-faq').hide();
        $('.seo-faq').show();
        $('.websites-faq').hide();

        $('.pricing-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.plans-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.seo-btn').css("background-color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.websites-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
      
        $('.pricing-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.plans-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.seo-btn').css("color", "#fff");
        $('.websites-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");

    } else if ($(this).hasClass('websites-btn')){

        $('.pricing-faq').hide();
        $('.plans-faq').hide();
        $('.seo-faq').hide();
        $('.websites-faq').show();

        $('.pricing-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.plans-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.seo-btn').css("background-color", "#fff");
        $('.websites-btn').css("background-color", "#a42d2f");
      
        $('.pricing-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.plans-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.seo-btn').css("color", "#a42d2f");
        $('.websites-btn').css("color", "#fff");
    }
});
  
});
</script>

I've left all the code in this time just in case the CSS changing in the jQuery is somehow messing up the other stuff.
Any help appreciated, thanks so much. Happy to provide the link to the site itself if needed, but I think that might be against the rules?
Thanks.

Are all the button elements added dynamically? Or do they exist when the page is loaded?

@Twisty That's a really great question. I was assuming they exist on page load, but I'm using Bricks Wordpress Theme so I'm not writing the code myself. So it's possible they are dynamic.

If they are Dynamically created, then your .on() should select a static parent element. Sort of like $(PARENTELEM).on('click tap touchstart', '.faq-btn', function(event){ }); to ensure the delegation of the event properly.

maybe you can provide more specific details about your issue by making a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Consider more efficient code. It may be better to hide all and set all colors as a blanket event and then update just the target.


jQuery(function($) {
  $(".brxe-container").hide();
  $('.faq-btn').on('click tap touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".brxe-container").hide();
    var target = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
    $("." + target + "-faq").show();
    $('.faq-btn').removeClass("highlight").addClass("dim");
    $(this).toggleClass("dim highlight");
  });
});
.highlight {
  background-color: #a42d2f;
  color: #fff;
}

.dim {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #a42d2f;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="brxe-button main-cta-button pricing-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">Pricing</button>
<button class="brxe-button main-cta-button plans-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">Plans</button>
<button class="brxe-button main-cta-button seo-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">SEO</button>
<button class="brxe-button main-cta-button websites-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">Websites</button>

<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container pricing-faq bricks-lazy-hidden">Pricing</div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container plans-faq bricks-lazy-hidden">Plans</div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container seo-faq bricks-lazy-hidden">SEO</div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container websites-faq bricks-lazy-hidden">Websites</div>




I'm brand new to jQuery so this is incredibly helpful, thanks so much. I'll test it out in a bit!

Alright, so I copied the code over and the page went completely white and kicked me out of my builder (Bricks)... not sure what happened lol.

@ThatBraxGuy do you see any Errors in Console? Not familiar with Bricks, so no reference to what you mentioned. You may need to move the code back into a different format, more like what you posted originally, unsure.
